# Localized storyboard is ignored (?)

Tags: cocoa-touch, localization, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I created a Swedish localization of my storyboard, but it doesn't get loaded for iOS devices with the language set to Swedish - it's always the English version.

I have `Localizable.strings` in `sv.lproj`, and those do work when using the `NSLocalizedString` macro.

Are there some additional steps required? All I did was click the plus sign under the "Localization" section.

[image: storyboards]
[image: settings]

Comment: Do you have Swedish in the app’s languages? Under Project -> Info tab, you have localizations.

Comment: Yeah, and it says "2 files localized", which must be the storyboard and `Localizable.strings`.

Comment: Weird, I have there only English (so far) and it also says "2 files localized", but I have no storyboards in the app, only settings bundle with `Root.strings` and the second one is `InfoPlist.strings`…

Comment: Check [Use single storyboard file for Base Internationalization in iOS 6](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446)

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional steps required except that when you get be ready to start working on localization (i. e. the storyboard is ready on your main application language), you should add localization to your project

[image: How to add localization to project]

and localize Storyboard for each language

[image]